# In Swift or Objective-C, how to get a jpeg image's current compression factor?

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, nsimage

Using Swift or Objective-C in a macOS application, I need some snippet to gather the current JPEG compression factor of an image file. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You can't get the compression factor, it is not known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.

> No, you can not and it does not make sense to do so, since there is no ubiquitous definition of the JPEG compression level. The actual result when saving a JPEG with compression level 60 in one software can differ significantly from what another software produces when set to level 60.

https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/88167/is-it-possible-to-find-out-what-compression-ratio-was-used-for-a-particular-jpeg